# Sql Optimization: Xml or Delimited String

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

This is hopefully just a simple question involving performance optimizations when it comes to queries in Sql 2008.

I've worked for companies that use Stored Procs a lot for their ETL processes as well as some of their websites.  I've seen the scenario where they need to retrieve specific records based on a finite set of key values.  I've seen it handled in 3 different ways, illustrated via pseudo-code below.

**Dynamic Sql that concatinates a string and executes it.**

```
EXEC('SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE xId IN (' + @Parameter + ')'
```

**Using a user defined function to split a delimited string into a table**

```
SELECT * FROM TableY INNER JOIN SPLIT(@Parameter) ON yID = splitId
```

**USING XML as the Parameter instead of a delimited varchar value**

```
SELECT * FROM TableZ JOIN @Parameter.Nodes(xpath) AS x (y) ON ...
```

While I know creating the dynamic sql in the first snippet is a bad idea for a large number of reasons, my curiosity comes from the last 2 examples.  Is it more proficient to do the due diligence in my code to pass such lists via XML as in snippet 3 or is it better to just delimit the values and use an udf to take care of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is now a 4th option - [table valued parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx), whereby you can actually pass a table of values in to a sproc as a parameter and then use that as you would normally a table variable. I'd be preferring this approach over the XML (or CSV parsing approach)

I can't quote performance figures between all the different approaches, but that's one I'd be trying - I'd recommend doing some real performance tests on them.

**Edit:**
A little more on TVPs. In order to pass the values in to your sproc, you just define a SqlParameter (SqlDbType.Structured) - the value of this can be set to any IEnumerable, DataTable or DbDataReader source. So presumably, you already have the list of values in a list/array of some sort - you don't need to do anything to transform it into XML or CSV.

I think this also makes the sproc clearer, simpler and more maintainable, providing a more natural way to achieve the end result. One of the main points is that SQL performs best at set based/not looping/non string manipulation activities.

That's not to say it will perform great with a large set of values passed in. But with smaller sets (up to ~1000) it should be fine.

Comment: Wouldn't this, often enough, just push the need to parse-n-load the data into tabular format upstream to the application? At which point, what's faster there -- XML or looping code parsing?

Comment: +1 Excellent explanation on how to use Table Parameters from the code side beyond DataReaders and DataTables.

Comment: +1, and TVPs have the best performance of all of these approaches as long as the TVP has a primary key.  For large `INSERT` operations I still use `BULK INSERT`, but for `JOIN` or `IN` queries I've thrown in anywhere up to 5000 items and not seen any really noticeable perf hit.

Answer (score 2):

`UDF` invocation is a little bit more costly than splitting the `XML` using the built-in function.

However, this only needs to be done once per query, so the performance difference will be negligible.

Comment: True for small sets. What about big ones, for various values of "big"?

Comment: @Philip: It's even truer for big sets. `TSQL` lacks pointers, so to parse the long strings it will call our good old friend Schlemiel the painter. `XML` parsing is done internally and optimized quite well.