# Whats the best way to persiste the contents of a jQuery sortable list?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple page with two lists. Using jQuery I have set the two lists as sortable and connected them together so I can add and remove from the list. This all works well.

I have come to the part of the feature where I need to save the results into the data store. When the user clicks on a submit button, there is an asynchronous request to an MVC controller that accepts a collection of strings.

I have two ideas on how to handle this scenario.

**Idea one**, remove all existing elements and re-create based on what is in the collection.

**Idea two**, loop through the list and add or update the sort order based on if a record already exists.

What this best way to do this and it there an option I have missed?

I'm using asp.net MVC with jQuery but this shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either method should work for your request.  The dumping and recreating "should" be less resource intensive than the insert and update method in idea two.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a little on the architecture of the table in the database. Would lots of deletions and inserts fragment the table indexes?

If the table indexes aren't a concern then a delete and recreate is likely to be both easier to develop and to perform better.

The other thing to give some consideration to in this scenario is [how you pass the lists to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245007/sql-optimization-xml-or-delimited-string).